# Laravel 6 database error : Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set up the relations between my migrations in Laralvel 6, but I still have this error message and I do not understand why ....

[image: error]

When I want to publish an article, it takes the query but returns empty tables.

Comment: please show us your PHP code, and speak english not french

Answer (score 0):

From the very limited information given, just by looking at the query it seems to be an issue with the `user_id`. In the insert stament there is no `user_id` inserted, which might be the problem? In your `Article` model, is `user_id` fillable?

If `user_id` isn't required, has it been made nullable in the migration for articles?

Please provide some examples of the migration, model and the method in the controller used for the create of the `Article`.